# Typescript: best way to construct an object that reference itself

Tags: typescript, object, self-reference

I am trying to migrate this simplified js code into ts:

```js
let Test = {};
Test.a = { //error: prop a does not exist
    someProp: true
};

Test.b = {
    ...Test.a,//self referencing
    otherProp: true
};

export default Test;
```

I want to **avoid extracting the object to an interface**, because the object has many props and I don't want to repeat all the props in the implementation.

Any suggestions?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/DYUwLgBAKiDOkF4IG8C+BuAUDeA6AhhEsphGRLAPYC2IACgE6UAOAXBGAwK4iYabY4YXACMiKUuVzScw-ABpJZSmAAWIBoxbtOPPlkwgAHs0oNIAExAAzfF2CRZ6IA)

Comment: Define an interface with optional, appropriately typed properties a and b, and declare Test an implementation of that interface.

Comment: this will end up in a huge code repetition, I have many props on the object. I will edit my question.

Comment: Which object references itself? Can you help clarify the title of this question, which is currently "Typescript: best way to construct an object that reference itself"? Right now, the object does not reference itself. It has an `a` property with value `{someProp:true}` and a `b` property with value `{someProp:true; otherProp: true}`. Nowhere does an object reference itself. Can you clarify what you need?

Comment: If your goal isn't to type it but only to make it compile, type it as `any`.

Comment: Define `Test` as `{ a: someType; b: someOtherType; }` Define `someType` as `{ someProp: boolean; }` Define `someOtherType` as `extends someType { otherProp: boolean; }` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgM4HsC2EAqBPABxQG80sIAFKdAgLmQCN10AbCOEAbmQF8AoUJFiIU6MAAto+IsggAPSCAAmqMtmklkYyVCo16TVuy68+bMMhwRUYeqTgB+ehnWEI3Bk60Spb7j2QAXmRiHk4+KxsAOjggkLVKajpkMCgAVxQwiOswKIY40iiiyNy4ABpvHT1k1IzecPkCdCgLJQh4NJYLEs4gA

Comment: @RayToal, I added a comment inside the code example. the self referencing is the usage of Test.a inside prop b, that is also a prop of Test. do you have any suggestions how to make the title clearer?

Comment: @IngoBürk, I need the object to be typed, it is an exposed object.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, the object itself is huge, repeating all the props will be a nightmare. Is there any way to make typescript infer automatically the type of this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result should still be correctly inferred when you re-arrange things a bit.

```
const a = {
    someProp: true
}
const b = {
    ...a,
    otherProp: true
}

const test = {a, b}

export default test;
```

The 'trick' to building up an object like this, is that you need to construct it all at once and not modify it in multiple steps. By reversing the order you achieve this.

Comment: the problem with this solution is that in my real app, Test is a huge object (it's an object containing maps of typography values to keys). This solution will be enormously bloated, while it looks like typescript can potentially infer the object type automatically somehow.